# Set Android permissions on a Visual Studio for Cordova Tools project

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

How do you add permissions like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in a Visual Studio tools for Apache Cordova project?

I can't figure out how because I didn't find any XML configuration file on which I can configure Android-specific settings.

Also, I'm using Visual Studio tools for Apache Cordova CTP3 on Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project has config.xml which is used to produce platform specific manifest but if you are interested in adding Android specific settings then place the custom AndroidManifest.xml file in the res/native/android folder to configure settings such as custom intents. Use the generated version of the file in the bld/Debug/platforms/android folder after building a Debug configuration of the project for Android. (Pulled from [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757053.aspx#NativeConfig))

Comment: I don't have platforms folder in bld/Debug, only a file changeList.json

Comment: @Abhishek could you provide a sample of the generated version of the file?

Comment: Does this mean we have to remember to edit the generated manifest file after each build?